# universal enveloping algebras and commutator subalgebras

Tags: lie-algebras, hopf-algebras, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ are Lie subalgebras of a Lie algebra $L$. $U(A)$,
$U(B)$ and $U(L)$ are the universal enveloping algebras of $A$, $B$
and $L$, respectively. Let $[A, B]$ be the Lie subalgebras generated
by the set {$[a, b]:a\in A, b\in B$} and $U([A, B])$ be he
universal enveloping algebras of $[A, B]$. I want to construct
$U([A, B])$ in terms of $U(A)$ and $U(B)$. I guess that $U([A, B])$
is the Hopf subalgebra of $U(L)$ generated by the set {$\sum
a_{1}b_{1}S(a_{2})S(b_{2}): a\in U(A), b\in U(B)$}, where $S$ is the
antipode of the Hopf algebra $U(L)$. Is that so?

Comment: What happens if `$A, B$` are nonzero but centralize each other?    It's best to work out a number of typical examples in order to get a precise formulation of the question.   (Also, does the characteristic of the underlying field matter, or not?)

Comment: @Jim Humphreys: Assume that $k$ is an arbitrary field and $[A, B]=0$. Then $\forall
a\in A, b\in B, \sum a_{1}b_{1}S(a_{2})S(b_{2})=\sum
a_{1}S(a_{2})b_{1}S(b_{2})=\epsilon(a)\epsilon(b)\in k$. In other
words, what I say is true when $k$ is an arbitrary field and $[A,
B]=0$.

Comment: @sife: Sorry for my hasty reading of your question.   But I'm still uncertain about what motivates it, and what examples have been looked at.  Does your formulation work in a simple Lie algebra (characteristic 0) for the pair consisting of a Borel subalgebra and its opposite, etc.?

Comment: @Jim:If my guess is true, then we can define the "commutator
subalgebra" of two Hopf subalgebra $W$ and $T$ to be the Hopf
subalgebra generated by the set {$\sum a_{1}b_{1}S(a_{2})S(b_{2}):
a\in W, b\in T$}. Because this definition is reasonable.

Comment: @Jim:Now Let $L$ be a simple Lie algebra over an algebraic closed
field of characteristic 0. Then commutator of the pair consisting of
a Borel subalgebra and its opposite is $L$.(I'm not sure whether I
misapprehend the last sentence of your second comment). Note that
$U([A, B])$ is contained in the Hopf subalgebra of $U(L)$ generated
by the set {$\sum a_{1}b_{1}S(a_{2})S(b_{2}): a\in U(A), b\in
U(B)$}. Therefore my guess is true in this case.

Comment: Just to see if I understand. If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ then $\sum a_1b_1S(a_2)S(b_2)=[a,b]$, by using the fact that $a$ and $b$ are primitive. So in each case your algebra is contained in $U([A,B])$. But beware that in $char k=p\ne 0$ also $a^{pn}$ and $b^{pm}$ are primitive hence your algebra would contain also $[a^{pn},b^{pm}]$ for any $n,m\in \mathbb N$. Is this wrong? More generally how do you show that the only primitive elements in your generated algebra are exactly $[a,b]$?

Comment: @Nicola Ciccoli: your questions feaze me, otherwise my guess won't be called a "guess"~

Comment: My point is as simple as that: since you're interested mainly in universal enveloping algebras and not in generic Hopf algebras have you looked first at primitive elements? To me it seems that primitive elements already shows that charachteristic of the underlying field matters.
(guess it's not easy to get this fact: using a word as "feaze" makes your comment for me harder than citing difficult theorems on Hopf algebras. In this community many readers are not mother tongue in English, please seek simplicity in your choice of words...)